# QR code reader on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I'm trying to use a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) reader on Ubuntu, but the drivers are only for Windows. Is there a possibility to use it on Ubuntu?

The model is *SL-QC15S*.

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0461:4d16 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1871:0101 Aveo Technology Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`xinput`:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NOVATEK USB Keyboard                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NOVATEK USB Keyboard                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 Camera                             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`ls /dev/video*`:

```
/dev/video0
```

I think it does need a driver, and I only have the Windows drivers. I think I can't scan codes because my QR code reader don’t have buttons to make a scan. The entry is this one:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1871:0101 Aveo Technology Corp.
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1871 Aveo Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x0101
  bcdDevice            0.0c
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          419
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0
      iFunction               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              2
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength           77
        dwClockFrequency       30.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00000000
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 3
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000053b
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          Backlight Compensation
          Power Line Frequency
        iProcessing             0
        bmVideoStandards     0x1a
          NTSC - 525/60
          SECAM - 625/50
          NTSC - 625/50
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {52f2b8aa-d18e-7249-8ced-96b17f04408b}
        bNumControl             1
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0x01
        iExtension              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               7
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            14
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         1
        wTotalLength                      215
        bEndPointAddress                  131
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       2
        bStillCaptureMethod                 2
        bTriggerSupport                     1
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                    27
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                5
        guidFormat                            {59555932-0000-1000-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
          bCopyProtect                      0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxBitRate                147456000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            160
        wHeight                           120
        dwMinBitRate                  9216000
        dwMaxBitRate                  9216000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       38400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                 36864000
        dwMaxBitRate                 36864000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      153600
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            176
        wHeight                           144
        dwMinBitRate                 12165120
        dwMaxBitRate                 12165120
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       50688
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            30
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            352
        wHeight                           288
        dwMinBitRate                 48660480
        dwMaxBitRate                 48660480
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      202752
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  1
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            18
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  3 (STILL_IMAGE_FRAME)
        bEndpointAddress                    0
        bNumImageSizePatterns               3
        wWidth( 0)                        640
        wHeight( 0)                       480
        wWidth( 1)                        320
        wHeight( 1)                       240
        wWidth( 2)                        160
        wHeight( 2)                       120
        bNumCompressionPatterns             3
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x020c  1x 524 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x030c  1x 780 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x03fc  1x 1020 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0bfc  2x 1020 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x13fc  3x 1020 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

[Windows drivers](https://mega.co.nz/#!RoxWXYab!nf4mIMa37z3zGpwSkBZ2WoeRcDoJ8iSuGcwKAkAGepo)

No, I don't have a webcam on my computer, only the QR code reader.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `lsusb`, `xinput` and `ls /dev/video*`. All with the scanner plugged?

Comment: Does it need a driver? I know from other barcode scanners that they present themselves as simply another input device, as if you had connected a keyboard. What happens if you open e.g. Gedit and scan a QR code?

Comment: What entry disappears on `lsusb` when you disconnect the reader?

Comment: Did you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 12):

It appears that your QR code reader is just a camera, and additional software is required to read the QR codes. You can use `zbarcam` from `zbar-tools` to read QR codes.

`zbarcam` will attempt to decode barcodes and QR codes from a video stream, and will output the contents of the scanned codes into stdout.

Comment: Usage can be found here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/zbarcam.1.html

Comment: It's a barcode reader: SL-QC15S http://www.sumlung.com/en/2d-barcode-reader.html

Comment: It shows up as a camera (that can stream video) and it has a CMOS image sensor. And besides, in [this video from SUMLUNG's website](http://www.sumlung.com/doc/qc15demo.wmv), you can see a small window on the screen which shows a streaming video of whatever's being placed in front of the scanning window.

Answer (score 8):

**QtQR** is simple QR code scanner using your webcam. It can be installed from the Software Center or from command line:

```
sudo apt-get install qtqr
```

Answer (score 2):

The device is simply a camera, the image processing and QR reading is made in the computer's "dirver". If do you want to use it in Linux as it were a "good" reader that has the reading part on the device (It acts as a keyboard that types all what you scan), you can follow these steps:

1. Install the required packages: `sudo apt-get install zbar-tools xdotool wmctrl`
2. Type on a terminal `gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/00-usb-qreader.rules`
3. A text editor will open up, copy and paste these lines:

   ```
      ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1871", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0101", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/<your_username>/.Xauthority", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", OWNER="<your_username>", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-qreader", SYMLINK+="qreader"
      ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1871", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0101", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/<your_username>/.Xauthority", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-qreader"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to find and replace all `<your_username>` occurrences by your username.
5. Save the file and close the text editor.
6. Type on a terminal `gksu gedit /usr/local/bin/usb-qreader`
7. On this file put these lines (you can customize it if you know what are doing):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   ZBAR_SETTINGS="--raw --nodisplay" # Put here the options
   ALWAYS_ON_TOP="true"              # Keep the zbar window always on top
   END_CHARACTER="Return"            # Character sent after code scan ("Return", "Tab", "space", "")
   TYPEIN_WINDOW=''                  # Title of the window onto type. If it's blank, it will type on the current window

   function scan() {
       zbarcam $ZBAR_SETTINGS /dev/qreader | while read line; do
           CODE=$(head -c -1 <<< "$line") 
           if [[ $TYPEIN_WINDOW != "" ]]; then
               WINDOW="--window $(xdotool search --name $TYPEIN_WINDOW | tail -n 1)"
           fi
           xdotool type $WINDOW "$CODE"
           xdotool key  $WINDOW "$END_CHARACTER"
       done
   }

   if [[ "${ACTION}" == "add" ]]; then
       scan &
       if [[ "$ALWAYS_ON_TOP" == "true" && ! "$OPTIONS" =~ "--nodisplay"  ]]; then
           while :; do wmctrl -l | grep -q "zbar barcode reader" && break; done
           wmctrl -r "zbar barcode reader" -b add,above
       fi
   elif [[ "${ACTION}" == "remove" ]]; then
       ps aux \
       | grep -e 'zbarcam.*/dev/qreader' \
       | grep -v grep \
       | awk '{print $2}' \
       | xargs -i kill {}
   fi
   ```

   8. Type on a terminal `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/usb-qreader`
   9. Reload the `udev` rules with this command: `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`
   10. Plug your awesome QR reader and enjoy!

However, if do you want a simple solution (that will not give the potential of this, but is simple) you can try the [@Slaci solution below](https://askubuntu.com/a/607646/387382).

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, you should use [CoBang](https://github.com/hongquan/CoBang) to scan QR code. This app was written recently by me, to catch new technologies in Linux desktop.

How to install in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ng-hong-quan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cobang
```